# Can I Have Only Specific Routes on GOOGLE_MAPS_API?

Tags: android, google-maps, routes

I'd like to know if I can alter the Google Maps API to only show certain routes.

I'm developing an app for our taxi association out here in South Africa.

The app has the basic functionality of an "Uber" service, however instead of typing the "Pickup" and "Destination" locations, I want the app to have pre-loaded routes to select from.

Haven't really tried anything as I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/overview) ([Directions API web service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions) and [Directions Service API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions)). In here, you can specify the `origin` and `destination` of the Directions API, and get the distance and travel time in a specific route, depending on the travel mode.

Here’s an example:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json
  ?avoid=highways
  &destination=Montreal
  &mode=bicycling
  &origin=Toronto
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

More examples can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-directions#ExampleRequests

Comment: Does this mean I would have to do each origin and destination separately. Would I be able to do the from a drop down perhaps, e.g “ Montreal to Toronto” then it gives me the routes etc?

Comment: Yes, you would have to specify each origin and destination separately. As for the drop down feature, you can use [Places Autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete). When you have the origin and destination (either you input them manually or through the dropdown feature of the Places Autocomplete API), Directions API will then gives you the directions route and travel time, depending on the travel mode.

Comment: Thank you for the help Elizabeth. I'll keep you up to speed.